# Validating a form using MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

In the book Professional MVC written by Hanselman/Guthrie, they show how to validate a form using built in helper methods and data anotations. This works, but requires a lot of manual boilerplate code.

Is there a new/easier way to validate input using some built in plumbing?

I'm using the Repository Pattern with Entity Framework.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by boilerplate code? I think the data annotations approach is very succinct, particulatly using your own derived implementations such as EmailAddress, StrongPassword etc.

Comment: I agree with @The Flower Guy here, first what do you mean by _boilerplate code_? Second using DataAnnotations is the preferred way to go with MVC, especially given you can write your own implementations (like this example (http://rlm.cc/hnRC0K) on my blog)

Comment: You also might want to consider using ViewModels for your Views and use the data annotations on them.  Then you won't have to annotate your Models directly if that bothers you.  I also agree with FlowerGuy on this.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, using Data Annotations is the new/easy way to do validation. The nice thing about using data annotations is that you can validate your models whenever you want, anywhere in your application. I generally setup a generic service to do as follows:

```
public class ValidationService<T> : IValidationService<T>
{
    public List<ValidationResult> Validate(T obj)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(
            obj,
            new ValidationContext(obj, null, null),
            results,
            true);
        return results;
    }
}
```

Then to validate a model:

```
var service = new ValidationsService<MyClass>();
var errors = service.Validate(myobject);
```

Considering how much functionality you get for such a small amount of code, Data Annotations are pretty powerful, especially when you consider how easy it is to write your own validation attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use ViewModels I highly recomend using [AutoMapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automapper-dn/) from souceforge

I agree with everyone that DataAnnotation is great - its ability to integrate with jQuery to offer client side validation without having to write a single line of jQuery sold it to me in a second!